Persistent Syntax error in Zoho Deluge Script
We are trying to create a Zoho Custom Function using Deluge script in Zoho Inventory. The script is as follows:
// Initialize pagination variables
page = 1;
has_more_records = true;

while (has_more_records)  // Correct structure of while loop
{
// Fetch items in batches of 200 (maximum limit per API call)
response = zoho.inventory.getRecords("Items", page, 200);

if (response.containKey("items"))  // Ensure response contains items
{
    items = response.get("items");
    for each item in items  // Loop through each item
    {
        stock_level = item.get("quantity");
        reorder_point = item.get("reorder_point");
        
        // Check if stock level is below the reorder point
        if (stock_level < reorder_point)
        {
            message = "Stock for item " + item.get("name") + " is below the reorder point. Current stock level: " + stock_level;
            
            // Send email notification
            sendmail
            [
                from : zoho.adminuserid  // Ensure no syntax errors in sendmail block
                to : "purchasing_team@example.com"
                subject : "Reorder Notification"
                message : message
            ];
        }
    }
    
    // Check if there are more records to fetch
    has_more_records = response.get("has_more_page");
    page = page + 1;
}
else
{
    has_more_records = false;
}}

But persistently I am getting the following error:
Check and update the code in line 5, position 23 as there is a Exception : Syntax error. Expecting ';'. Found '{'.

Clearly there is no scope for a ; here in the structure of a while loop. Please guide me regarding the resolution.

It is quite a late  answer for you but, Deluge does not natively support while loops. that is why it is expecting you to close the line of code but instead it gets a curly brace.
See While Loops in Deluge by Lee Van Buskirk to elaborate on how you could create a for each loop to act like a while loop.
